# TMC2130 stallGuard - SG_Result always 0

Tags: stepper-motor

I'm working with the TMC2130 and I want to setup the stallGuard. The problem is that SG_Result in register DRV_Status is always 0. It doesn't matter with how much load the motor has to drive or how I set the sensitivity (SGT in register COOLCONF). I'm driving the motor in spreadCycle and the SPI is working properly.

The only register settings I make are:

1. toff = 3 (for spreadCylce)
2. tbl = 2 (for spreadCylce)
3. 1/16 Microstep

I played with SGT but as already said, SG_Result is always 0. Am i doing something wrong or where could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It acutally was a hardware mistake. DCEN_CFG4 (pin 18) was not tied to ground, so the driver was still in DcStep mode.